# How to see how many times a variable appears in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a arrayList of properties and I need to see if properties in a city appear more than 4000 times, if so i color my button.

```
 for(AirbnbListing abnb : List){
        for(Button btn : arr) {     
            if(btn.getText().equals(abnb.getCity())) {                    
                btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF4500");                  
            }
        }
    }
```

Once my button equals the city name I want it to check it there are 4000 properties, but I am unsure how to do this. Can someone help me out.

Can I do something similar to this?

```
  if(btn.getText().equals(abnb.getCity()) && abnb.getCity().size() > 4000)
```

Comment: I know my suggestion doesn't work but i was hoping for something similar to this

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group the properties by city so you can aggregate the counts:

```
Map<String, Long> counts = List.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(AirbnbListing::getCity, Collectors.counting()));
```

Then just iterate through the buttons and lookup the count from your map:

```
for (Button btn : arr) {
    if (counts.getOrDefault(btn.getText(), 0L) > 4000) {
        btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FF4500");
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, I spent a whole day on this